# How to understand the type of storage of a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, storage

I have as an homework this task:

> Given a `void** ptr_addr` write a function that return 0 if the type of storage of `*ptr_addr` is static or automatic and return 1 if the type of storage of `*ptr_addr` is dynamic.
> The language of the code must be C.

The problem is that theoretically I know what the task is about but I don't know how to check the
previous condition with a code.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There's no way to do this using only the features of standard C.

Comment: Don't they teach the required concepts before assigning homework? It's been 40 years since I was in college, but that's how I remember it working.

Comment: @Barmar now i am more confused than before...

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a reasonable homework exercise. It's not something you should ever need to do when programming, and C doesn't provide a standard way to  do it.

Comment: Are you supposed to be making assumptions about the range of addresses used for the data segment, stack, and heap?

Comment: There's no facility in standard C that can give you that information - you'd have to know how your system partitions its memory for dynamic vs. non-dynamic objects.  That's not to say it can't be done at all in C, just that you have to either use some system-specific extension or have outside knowledge of your system architecture.

Comment: The homework is probably wrong for some reason (maybe it is bad written or something, or maybe the professor has told you something important to understand how to handle this kind of homeworks), anyway apparently this homework is asking to check whether a pointer is a heap pointer or not (e.g.: if the pointer has been generated by `malloc()` etc.) and the only (very bad) way I know to check this condition is to use `realloc()` on the pointer: if `realloc()` crashes your program, then you probably have a pointer not to the heap.

Comment: Theoretically, and under the older, simpler Unix memory layout model, if you knew the addresses of end of the text segment and the data segment and the uninitialized data segment, and of the bottom of the stack, you could figure these things out.  And if you knew about the magic symbols `etext` and `edata` and the system call `sbrk`, you'd have a good start towards finding some of those, and you could probably contrive to use a dummy local variable in one of your own functions to make a reasonable (albeit approximate) guess about the stack bottom.  But whether any of that works today...???

Comment: Now that I think about it, one could add a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`: when you call `realloc()` on the pointer and the output of `realloc()` is not `NULL`, you have a heap pointer; instead, if `realloc()` fails, it will trigger a `SIGSEGV` that you can catch with a handler, so you know that the pointer is not a dynamic one. It would a quite tricky code to write, it would not be thread-safe probably, but it may work. But I think it's just madness for a homework to ask something tricky like that.

Comment: If you're on Linux you can read /proc/{pid}/maps to know where each segment is.

Comment: It can't work.  C doesn't require a stack or a heap so there are no specific places for these things to be allocated.  The fact that computer architectures make stacks and heaps a convenient way to implement dynamic memory and local variables doesn't mean it is the only way.

Comment: giacomo landi, Adding an OS  tag would help, as there is no general solution.

Answer (score 9):

Normally I don't do homework, but in cases like this I may make an exception.

Bear in mind that what I'm about to present is *horrible code*.  Also it doesn't meet your requirements as stated — you'll have to adapt it for that.  Also it may not meet your instructor's expectations: for an instructor demented enough to be assigning this task, I can't begin to guess his (her? its?) expectations.  You may get dinged for using the technique I've presented, or for presenting someone else's work.  Also *I'm* going to get dinged for presenting this code here on Stack Overflow, because no, it's nothing like portable or guaranteed to do anything, let alone to work.  I have no idea whether it'll work on your system.

Nevertheless, and may God help me, I tested it, and it does "work" on a modern Debian Linux system.

```
#include <unistd.h>

extern etext, edata, end;

char *
mcat(void *p)
{
    int dummy;
    if(p < &etext)
         return "text";
    else if(p < &edata)
         return "data";
    else if(p < &end)
         return "bss";
    else if(p < sbrk(0))
         return "heap";
    else if(p > &dummy)
         return "stack";
    else return "?";
}
```

You'll get a good number of warnings if you compile this, which could theoretically be silenced using some explicit casts, but I think the warnings are actually pretty appropriate, given the nefariousness of this code.

How it works: on at least some Unix-like systems, [`etext`, `edata`, and `end`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/etext) are magic symbols corresponding to the ends of the program's text, initialized data, and uninitialized data segments, respectively.  [`sbrk(0)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) gives you a pointer to the top of the heap that a traditional implementation of `malloc` is using.  And `&dummy` is a good approximation of the bottom of the stack.

Test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int g = 2;
int g2;
    
int main()
{
    int l;
    static int s = 3;
    static int s2;
    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("g: %s\n", mcat(&g));
    printf("g2: %s\n", mcat(&g2));
    printf("main: %s\n", mcat(main));
    printf("l: %s\n", mcat(&l));
    printf("s: %s\n", mcat(&s));
    printf("s2: %s\n", mcat(&s2));
    printf("p: %s\n", mcat(p));
}
```

On my test system this prints

```
g: data
g2: bss
main: text
l: stack
s: data
s2: bss
p: heap
```

Comment: Curious, why `p < &etext` and not `p <= &etext`, etc?

Comment: That's a clever trick, don't be ashamed of it.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Given the way these symbols are defined, for the same reason we don't use `<=` when iterating over an array.  Indeed I would expect the address of the first initialized static-duration variable to be equal to `&etext`.

Comment: Thanks. [etext](https://linux.die.net/man/3/etext)  (IMO, name is off-by-one.)

Comment: It is only if linker script emits those symbols

Comment: Not only do symbols like `etext` exist in this implmenation, `p < &edata` is also defined.  `p < &edata` is UB per C.

Comment: @0___________ Hey, this technique worked before "linker scripts" even existed! :-)

Comment: `end` has been around since Unix v6 and I have used these symbols circa 1981 on Unix v7, System III, System V, and onward... They are provided by `ld` in posix systems and are language agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post a different approach to solve the problem:

```c
// this function returns 1 if ptr has been allocated by malloc/calloc/realloc, otherwise 0
int is_pointer_heap(void* ptr) {
    pid_t p = fork();

    if (p == 0) {
        (void) realloc(ptr, 1);
        exit(0);
    }

    int status;
    
    (void) waitpid(p, &status, 0);

    return (status == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

I wrote this (bad) code very quickly (and there's lot of room for improvements), but I tested it and it seems to work.

EXPLANATION: `realloc()` will crash your process if the argument passed to it is not a `malloc/calloc/realloc`-allocated pointer. Here we create a new child process, we let the child process call `realloc()`; if the child process crashes, we return `0`, otherwise we return `1`.