# I know an address, but how should I judge in what section? Global area or heap area or stack area using C

Tags: c, heap-memory, allocation, memory-address, stack-memory

I have a C language programming interview, and the question is: know an address, how to judge in what section? Global area or heap area or stack area.

Comment: It really depends on the system and platform.

Comment: You can probably use heuristics by comparing addresses of objects of which you know where they are stored to those in question. The addresses of the different categories should be far apart unless the program is using a lot of memory: Typically stack and heap grow towards each other and start on opposite ends of the address space. So objects in each group that were allocated around the same time tend to be close to each other, in different groups far apart. But it's only a heuristic ;-).

Comment: for gcc look for the sysmbols from default linker script which marh beginning and end of standard sections

Comment: See [How to understand the type of storage of a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68839542).

Comment: Re *"know an address, how to judge in what section"*: Was the interview question actually in broken English? If it was, what does it tell you about the company?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Potentially the question was asked in [Mandarin or Cantonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenzhen#Languages), and the OP translated it or piped it through google translate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, you can compare the address in question to the addresses of known objects that are global, on the stack or on the heap. It is likely that the address will belong to the same storage category as the closest address. Below is a demonstration. The interesting part is the function `guessStorageLoc()`.

I have allocated large dummy objects so that the tested objects are not directly adjacent to the reference objects which seemed too easy.

Edit: The address differences looked fishy — we have to us `llabs()` for long longs on a 64 bit system or the differences are narrowed to 32 bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// This program demonstrates a heuristic to guess 
// whether a given address is global, on the stack 
// or on the heap. 
// Provide any command line argument to get an output of the addresses.
// Tested with gcc 10.2 under msys and VS 2019.

int globalGap1[2000*2000];
int globalRefObj;
int globalGap2[2000*2000];

int globalTestObj;

intptr_t refStack;
enum storageLocE { STACK, GLOBAL, HEAP };
static const char* enumNames[] = { "STACK", "GLOBAL", "HEAP" };

int verbose;

enum storageLocE guessStorageLoc(void* p)
{
    intptr_t ip = (intptr_t)p;

    // ip itself is on the stack and can bserve as reference;-)
    intptr_t refStack= (intptr_t)&ip; 
    intptr_t refHeap = (intptr_t)malloc(sizeof(int));
    intptr_t refGlob = (intptr_t)&globalRefObj;

    size_t heapDiff = llabs(ip - refHeap);
    size_t stackDiff = llabs(ip - refStack);
    size_t globDiff = llabs(ip - refGlob);

    if (verbose)
    {
        printf("Address in question: %p (%"PRIxPTR")\n", p, ip);
        printf("ref stack: %"PRIxPTR", diff: %zu\n", refStack, stackDiff);
        printf("ref heap:  %"PRIxPTR", diff: %zu\n", refHeap, heapDiff);
        printf("ref glob:  %"PRIxPTR", diff: %zu\n", refGlob, globDiff);
    }                                        
    if (heapDiff < stackDiff)
    {
        return heapDiff < globDiff ? HEAP : GLOBAL;
    }
    // ok, closer to stack than heap
    return stackDiff < globDiff ? STACK : GLOBAL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    verbose = argc > 1; // any argument will do ;-)

    int stackTestObj;
    int stackGapDummy[1000];

    int* dynamicTestAddr = malloc(sizeof(int));
    malloc(1000 * 1000); // gap

    printf("\nstack object: guess is %s\n\n", enumNames[guessStorageLoc(&stackTestObj)]);
    printf("\nheap object: guess is %s\n\n", enumNames[guessStorageLoc(dynamicTestAddr)]);
    printf("\nglobal object: guess is %s\n\n", enumNames[guessStorageLoc(&globalTestObj)]);
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-result -o GuessStorageCategory GuessStorageCategory.c && ./GuessStorageCategory xxx
Address in question: 0xffffcc24 (ffffcc24)
ref stack: ffffbc18, diff: 4108
ref heap:  800000450, diff: 30064785452
ref glob:  101349400, diff: 20236252

stack object: guess is STACK

Address in question: 0x800000430 (800000430)
ref stack: ffffbc18, diff: 30064789528
ref heap:  8000004c0, diff: 144
ref glob:  101349400, diff: 30044549168

heap object: guess is HEAP

Address in question: 0x10228b820 (10228b820)
ref stack: ffffbc18, diff: 36240392
ref heap:  8000004e0, diff: 30028549312
ref glob:  101349400, diff: 16000032

global object: guess is GLOBAL
```

**But wait! If we apply optimization we get a wrong result:**

```
$ gcc -O3 -Wall -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-result -o GuessStorageCategory GuessStorageCategory.c && ./GuessStorageCategory xxx
Address in question: 0xffffcc1c (ffffcc1c)
ref stack: ffffcb98, diff: 132
ref heap:  800000450, diff: 30064785460
ref glob:  101349420, diff: 20236292

stack object: guess is STACK

Address in question: 0x800000430 (800000430)
ref stack: ffffcb98, diff: 30064785560
ref heap:  8000004c0, diff: 144
ref glob:  101349420, diff: 30044549136

heap object: guess is HEAP

Address in question: 0x100407010 (100407010)
ref stack: ffffcb98, diff: 4236408
ref heap:  8000004e0, diff: 30060549328
ref glob:  101349420, diff: 16000016

global object: guess is STACK
```

The reason is probably that global and stack objects are close together to begin with; the compiler now eliminates the unused stack "gap" allocations that move the stack reference object away from the global memory. But the compiler cannot eliminate the unused *global* gap variables separating the global reference and test objects; they are exported symbols and are considered a sort of observable behavior by the compiler.

If we  make them file static so that they are no longer visible symbols from outside the program the compiler is free to eliminate them, placing the reference and the test variable in adjacent storage which leads to the expected result.

This is, of course, a cautionary event: We are really only doing heuristics. Unlucky allocation patterns may make this heuristic fail.